# In Fedora 17 kde I don't know user or password to authenticate printer installation

Tags: fedora, authentication

I am trying to set up a new computer with Fedora 17 and KDE both working ok. I have plugged in an HP laser USB printer, and am trying to set it up. I enter "system settings -> printers" from the KDE menu, and am asked for a user name and password for authentication. There I get stuck, nothing I can remember gets me any further.

I have no problem with `su` or `sudo` from the terminal window, nor with the printer on my previous machine with Fedora 12.

Please can anyone help me out of this impasse?

Incidentally, although this is on a dual boot machine, with grub, I have no file `grub.cfg` or anything like it.

Comment: Fedora 17 is long end-of-life

Comment: Have you tried giving it the root user's password?

Comment: @Nigel, Yes I tried all the relevant passwords I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions. I had a lot of other troubles with that installation, all due to my own misunderstandings, so, in the end I backed up the little work I had already done, and simply re-installed Linux Fedora 17, I made a careful note of the passwords I used, and have done one "Authentication" all right so far; not the printer, I haven't got to that yet.

Other issues with `grub` are still there, but they will be the subject of another question.

I take the point about Fedora 17, but I happened to have the installation DVD handy, and: "if it works (as I am sure it will) don't fix it" is my guiding principle.

Comment: I wouldn't beat myself up with that comment either. Vonbrand is right, but the point is a bit of "so what?". Use what you have, the distro on that DVD is still valid to use and learn from, at some point upgrade it if you choose to do so, it isn't the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sudo` privileges you should be able to do this:

```
$ sudo system-config-printer
```

If this dialog cannot come up after providing credentials to `sudo` then the credentials that you're being asked for are likely for a CUPS server that isn't necessarily your local server. This is the system whose username/password you're being prompted for.